# UIImage.draw() function not working in viewDidLoad() callback

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

In the `viewDidLoad()` callback below, why does the `image?.draw()` function not work?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named:"0")
        image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    // more code here
}
```

Comment: Your code is illegal, and you should be getting error messages in the console telling you so.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show it on your storyboard scene? If so, add a `UIImageView` to your scene and then set its `image`. If you're trying to do something else, let us know what you're trying to do...

Comment: I just did not understand it. I learnt it on standford open classes by Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of a UIImage draws a image at a [current graphic context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623918-uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext). In the method viewDidLoad no a graphic context.
Move the calling of the drawing into [draw](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) method of some custom view.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thank you.